# difference between octomap and voxel grid?

Tags: ros, octomap, voxel-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone,
I am new in ROS, and I would like to know the defference betwen octomap and voxel_grid ?
I have looking for information on internet but I have find the same information for both of them.
I have seen these videos about octomap and voxel_grid on youtube ( watch?v=y5tGI3Fln_4 and watch?v=y5tGI3Fln_4 )

If someone can explain the defference to me, or guide me to a webpage ?

thank you,

Guillaume

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186783/difference-between-octomap-and-voxel-grid?/) by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 312 on 2014-07-16

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Octomap is based on [Octtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) . which can be multi resolution map. [....slides](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Ehornunga/pub/hornung13roscon.pdf)

[Octtree http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Octree2.png](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Octree2.png)

---

And Voxel grid is like 3d occupancy grid map with fixed resolution.

[Voxel grid http://www.critterai.org/projects/cainav/doc/media/Heightfield-VoxelGrid.jpg](http://www.critterai.org/projects/cainav/doc/media/Heightfield-VoxelGrid.jpg))

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on 2014-07-17**:
thank you!

**Comment by [Brycecccccchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34056/brycecccccchen/) on 2018-07-22**:
Which one is faster (or better)?

**Comment by [vijayaganesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/37945/vijayaganesh/) on 2018-10-07**:
OcTree is faster and hence better.